# How to access <T> from function types in following syntax

Tags: typescript

Below is abstracted version of types in a project I am working on

```
// types.ts
interface Methods {
  request<T>(params: RequestParams): Promise<T>;
}

// implementation.ts
public request: Methods["request"] = async <T>(params) => {
  // ...
};
```

I was assuming that I would be able to access `<T>` as above, but as soon as I add it, `params` becomes untyped / any for some reason

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally others could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/NVZpBN) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write an assignment with a generic type, TypeScript won't infer the type of an assigned value from the variable type. It just verifies that the type of the assigned value (`<T>(params: any): Promise<T>`) is compatible with the variable type (`<T>(params: RequestParams): Promise<T>`), according to the duck typing rules.

So you shouldn't expect `params` to be typed automatically, but you should type it yourself instead:

```
// types.ts
interface Methods {
  request<T>(params: RequestParams): Promise<T>;
}

// implementation.ts
public request: Methods["request"] = async <T>(params: RequestParams) => {
  // ...
};
```

[TypeScript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAShCOBXCBnYAFAhgJ0wWxSgF4oBvTALijWwEsA7AcwG4BfZqAek6gGVhM9ACYBaBlFCQAsAChZ3CeFQA6YClkNgEbADNMAY2gBZCMAAWAeyGFSsqPajYEyNAB4AKgD4AFGBz4UKjgkVAx-AgBKKnRsCzxaFAgPT2ZZVll5Hlo8MAAbCDwIegFgWgt6VXUZfVzMFEIAUQAPfDzoWxkHKDBEACNc2n1HZ1CqE3MrFABtACInELQZgF1iKDqQeiHk33DA2BG0LFxI4k8yOy6HBQApRDQ16gFhMXooHQtsCTNofStoc0wwG6sSEiEMhHM0AABu4oVAAG6YXLIC6XYbARDYV5+Y6EOpreggNaEdypToOdhpWRAA)

Comment: Ah, so there is no way to avvoid re-typing params in this case? I came to this solution as well, was hoping for something more "automatic", but thank you for confirming.